# Error in `auto.arima` in R: AIC value approximated

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am running an ARIMA model for my forecasts in R

My data set is 1 month's data.
It has 2976 observations which has a frequency of 15 min. I recieve data every 15 min.
There is little seasonality in the data.
I am trying to fit an ARIMA model using `auto.arima` for forecast of 24 tie steps.

This error shows up: `AIC value approximated`.
Can one ignore this? If not then what is the way around?

Comment: The answer to your question depends crucially on: - which software you're using - what type of inference you have in mind - the finer details of your model Without this information nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: historical dat is 1 month..

Comment: Auto.arima is unfit for this type of problem, please read the accompanying manual.

Comment: @forecaster, could you indicate *why* you think `auto.arima` does not fit this problem? I do not immediately see a reason.

Comment: There could be hourly effects .. there could be day of the week effects. There could be level shifts or local time trends in the data . There could be one-time anomolous data values . There could be changes in parameters over time . There could be changes in error variance over time. The list goes on and on . Keep models simple BUT not too simple...... Occam's razor suggests simplicity BUT not too simple